# Satisfying dependency errors whilst building Debian Jessie live CD with simple-cdd

Tags: debian, debian-jessie, preseed

I am trying to build a Debian install CD with [simple-cdd](https://wiki.debian.org/Simple-CDD), which is recommended as the easiest way to create a custom installer.  The CD will have a few extra packages and a preseed file.

Before adding any customisation I ran the tool to test a basic build:

```
$ build-simple-cdd --dist jessie --logfile log.txt
```

This fails with dependency errors, one example is `vim-tiny`:

```
2017-03-01 16:19:48,250 WARNING     package: vim-tiny
2017-03-01 16:19:48,250 WARNING     version: 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u1
2017-03-01 16:19:48,250 WARNING     architecture: amd64
2017-03-01 16:19:48,250 WARNING     status: broken
2017-03-01 16:19:48,250 WARNING     reasons:
2017-03-01 16:19:48,250 WARNING      -
2017-03-01 16:19:48,250 WARNING       missing:
2017-03-01 16:19:48,250 WARNING        pkg:
2017-03-01 16:19:48,250 WARNING         package: vim-tiny
2017-03-01 16:19:48,250 WARNING         version: 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u1
2017-03-01 16:19:48,250 WARNING         architecture: amd64
2017-03-01 16:19:48,251 WARNING         unsat-dependency: vim-common (= 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u1)
```

It's evident from the [vim-common changelog](http://metadata.ftp-master.debian.org/changelogs/main/v/vim/vim_7.4.488-7+deb8u2_changelog) that the requested version has been superseded by a security update (version `deb8u1` was replaced with `deb8u2`).  The actual dependency requirement is:

```
Looking at list, line "vim-tiny"
+ Trying to add vim-tiny...
    vim-tiny Dep: vim-common (= 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u1)  soft_depend 0
      vim-common is included already, but invalid version 2:7.4.488-7+deb8u2
    vim-common not included in a useful version, check_backports 0
```

Looking at the full log it seems the package is available but deleted by reprepro:

```
2017-03-01 16:17:14,385 DEBUG mirror/reprepro stdout: deleting and forgetting pool/main/v/vim/vim-common_7.4.488-7+deb8u1_amd64.deb
```

So it seems that some part of the base operating system requires vim-tiny, which requires a specific version of vim-common.  That version isn't available due to a security release.

Note that vim-tiny is just an illustration, there is another unmet dependency for BIND which also recently got a security update.

Is there a way to ensure simple-cdd builds the CD regardless?  Or disable package deletion, as the first `apt-get upgrade` should pull these in correctly.

Comment: Try to add `--extra-udeb-dist` option

Comment: Adding `--extra-udeb-dist stretch` generates the same errors as above.

Comment: Why `stretch` if you using `jessie` ?

Comment: Same errors with `--extra-udeb-dist jessie` too.

Comment: best solution is to upgrade `vim-tiny` to the latest version too.  i'm not familiar with this tool to know why it's grabbing the older version.